# 1 Long Beep - PC Won't Boot - Just Assembled

Tags: boot, motherboard

I put together a PC with parts that I had. One PC was working fine, until something happened and all of a sudden it stopped working. I'm not sure the exact cause, but what I can tell you is that when I tried to turn on the PC, it would just run the fans inside the case and pressing the power button would do nothing.

Now I have switched this old motherboard with a FIC K8-800T mobo and put everything back together. When I boot it up now, it gives me one long beep right before it attempts to boot from the CD. There's no CD so it begins to boot Windows, but then it just goes slow. It won't even load the loading screen.

Does this mean my CPU is bad or is there a way to fix this? I may have put a cord or two in the wrong place on the motherboard, I'm not quite a genius with computers, but I definitely know my way around them.

Comment: check your ram , it might be loose

Comment: You should find an explanation of error codes (beeps) in the documentation for your mainboard. Mainboards usually output error codes as beeps to assure they can be heard even if there is no display attached (or the display is not working).

Comment: It's not the RAM, and the error codes are not documented in the manual. The display is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the [manual](ftp://ftp.fic.com.tw/motherboard/manual/socket754/k8m-800t/) of your motherboard. Unfortunately it doesn't document the boot beep codes, but it may help you check your installation.

- See that your RAM and any AGP/PCI cards are properly seated.
- If your video card has a connector for auxiliary power, make sure it's connected.
- If you have two RAM modules, try booting with them individually to rule out faulty memory.
- Check the BIOS memory test result (disable `Quick Power On Self Test` from BIOS to run extensive memory test).
- Remove all hardware that is not necessary for booting and see if there's any effect.

It is very likely that Windows has a hard time booting if there are e.g. old motherboard's chipset drivers installed. To be sure, try a clean OS installation.

Comment: Great answer, but there's also one more problem. My keyboard is not working! I can't get into the BIOS or anything without a keyboard. This problem I'm sure lies with the keyboard or the keyboard outlet, but it's prevents me from trying one of your suggestions above.

Comment: @Jared: Is it a USB keyboard? Try a PS/2 keyboard (round connector) to rule out USB detection problems.